# How to predict when Jack-in-the-Box zombies are about to explode in endless survival?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

[image]

These zombies are pretty easy to kill, only it seems that sometimes they explode prematurely and take down a whole bunch of plants.

So what are the signs that they are about to explode and what triggers explosion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe their explosion is entirely random at each step.  However, you know that they are about to explode because they stop a moment before and have a startled look on their face.

Answer (score 2):

If you hit a lot of damage to them, they will explode much later.
And they stop before it explodes

Answer (score 0):

I dont play the endless version that much, but the explosive zombies are un-predictable. You can only tell because they stay still and get a weird expression on their face.

Answer (score -1):

They explode after 15 seconds after they appear on screen